# Make countdown timer start after link is clicked by user

Tags: html

How can I create a countdown timer for the links on my site?
After a user clicked a link the countdown timer should start. For example I have a link `Link 1`. When a user clicks on `Link 1` the countdown timer should start.

Can I create a countdown timer for all links?

I would like to display the countdown timer opposite of the link. For example: when a user clicks a link this timer "01:59:59" should appear opposite of link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to display the timer.

```
window.setTimeout(function, milliseconds);
```

and what exactly do you mean by "display countdown timer opposite of link"?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer Akshay Gupta and Sumeet Jain . My mean when a user clicked My Link. The time start to show remaining hours to next click. Like this
 
My Link: 11 Hours, 25 Minutes, 47 Seconds is remaining next click

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```js
function countdown(elementName, minutes, seconds) {
  var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

  function twoDigits(n) {
    return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
  }

  function updateTimer() {
    msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
    if (msLeft < 1000) {
      element.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";
    } else {
      time = new Date(msLeft);
      hours = time.getUTCHours();
      mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
      element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits(mins) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits(time.getUTCSeconds());
      setTimeout(updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500);
    }
  }

  element = document.getElementById(elementName);
  endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60 * minutes + seconds) + 500;
  updateTimer();
}
```

```html
<a onclick='countdown("countdown",
120,0);' href="#">Timer</a>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

> Just update the time in minutes in Anchor tag with your own.